# VBA - How to download .xls from website and put data into excel file

Tags: vba, excel, web

I managed to use VBA to get to the point where I'm ready to download an excel file from the web but I'm having trouble figuring out how to actually download that file and put its contents into an excel file I'm working in. Any suggestions? Thanks

Here is the code so far:

```
Sub GetData()

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As HTMLDocument
Dim objElement As HTMLObjectElement

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
With IE
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "http://www.housepriceindex.ca/default.aspx"
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    .Document.getElementById("lnkTelecharger2").Click
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: Wend
    Set HTMLDoc = .Document
    Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("txtEmailDisclaimerEN")
    objElement.Value = "abc@abc.com"
    Set objElement = HTMLDoc.getElementById("lnkAcceptDisclaimerEN")
    objElement.Click

    ' ... Get CSV somehow ...

    '.Quit

End With

Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use list objects, create a datatable from CSV and bind your csv to the list object.
Or simply read and set the cell contents based on the csv file,

Comment: Could you show me how to do that with code? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportHistoricalDataSheet()

    Const SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS = 13056
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

    Dim aBody, sPath

    ' Download Historical Data xls file via XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    'With CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
        '.SetOption 2, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
        .Open "GET", "http://www.housepriceindex.ca/Excel2.aspx?langue=EN&mail=abc%40abc.com"
        .Send
        ' Get binary response content
        aBody = .responseBody
        ' Retrieve filename from headers and concatenate full path
        sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Replace(Split(Split(.GetAllResponseHeaders, "filename=", 2)(1), vbCrLf, 2)(0), "/", "-")
    End With
    ' Save binary content to the xls file
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .Write aBody
        .SaveToFile sPath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
    ' Open saved workbook
    With Workbooks.Open(sPath, , True)
        ' Get 1st worksheet values to array
        aBody = .Worksheets(1).UsedRange.Value
        .Saved = True
        .Close
    End With
    ' Delete saved workbook file
    CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").DeleteFile sPath, True
    ' Insert array to target worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(aBody, 1), UBound(aBody, 2)).Value = aBody

End Sub
```

Comment: this is fantastic! How would I go about making it update the same sheet instead of creating a brand new one (because I intend to make links and create graphs, would make it much easier).

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine I changed the code just to update the values on the `Sheet1`.

Comment: The code works great, one small thing: how would I go about making the code work accross multiple versions of excel (2007 & 2013). It's excel 12.0 and 15.0 object library that is causing the issue. I've researched "late binding" but I'm not sure how to apply it to the code. Thanks in advance

Comment: @RageAgainstheMachine there are alreay late bindings in the code, could you please describe what is the exact issue caused by Excel object library?