# Return focus to ThisWorkbook.Activesheet after XMLHTTP60 file download

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping, focus

Situation:

I am unable to return focus to the Excel application after initiating a file download.

My usual tricks of `AppActivate` and `Application.hwnd` , when working between applications, don't seem to be working this time. I haven't had a problem doing this before so don't know if I am being particularly dense today, or, it is because I am involving a browser for the first time. I suspect it is the former.

Questions:

1) Can any one see where I am going wrong (why focus does not shift back to Excel)?

2) More importantly: Is there a way to download files in the background, using the default browser, keeping the focus on `ThisWorkbook` and thereby avoiding the issue altogether?

I am using a workaround of `SendKeys "%{F4}"` immediately after the download, at present, to close the browser and so am defaulting back to Excel.

Note: The default browser in my case is Google Chrome but clearly could be any browser.

What I have tried:

1) From @[user1452705](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481674/vba-api-declarations-bring-window-to-front-regardless-of-application); focus didn't shift:

```
Public Declare Function SetForegroundWindow _
Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long

Public Sub Bring_to_front()
    Dim setFocus As Long
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    setfocus = SetForegroundWindow(Application.hwnd)
End Sub
```

2) Then I tried:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate 'No shift in focus

Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name).Activate 'Nothing happened

Application.Windows(ThisWorkbook.Name & " - Excel").Activate 'Subscript out of range
```

3) `AppActivate` using Title as actually displayed in Window:

```
AppActivate "AmbSYS_testingv14.xlsm" & " - Excel" 'Nothing happened
```

4) More desperate attempts:

```
AppActivate Application.Caption 'Nothing happened

AppActivate ThisWorkbook.Name & " - Excel" 'Nothing happened

AppActivate ThisWorkbook.Name 'Nothing happened

AppActivate "Microsoft Excel" 'Invalid proc call
```

4) Finally, the current version of my code is using @[ChipPearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ActivateExcelMain.aspx)'s sub `ActivateExcel` , which also has no effect:

Module 1:

```
Public Sub DownloadFiles()
'Tools > ref> MS XML and HTML Object lib
    Dim http As XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As HTMLDocument

    Set http = New XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New HTMLDocument

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/ambulance-quality-indicators/ambulance-quality-indicators-data-2017-18/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    'Test Download code
    html.getElementsByTagName("p")(4).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).Click

   ' Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 3)   'pause for downloads to finish before files

   'Other code

    ActivateExcel

End Sub
```

Module 2:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' modActivateExcel
' By Chip Pearson, www.cpearson.com, chip@cpearson.com
' http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ActivateExcelMain.aspx
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Window API Declarations
' These Declares MUST appear at the top of the
' code module, above and before any VBA procedures.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Private Declare PtrSafe Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal HWnd As Long) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" ( _
ByVal lpClassName As String, _
ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetFocus Lib "user32" ( _
ByVal HWnd As Long) As Long

Public Sub ActivateExcel()
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' ActivateExcel
' This procedure activates the main Excel application window,
' ("XLMAIN") moving it to the top of the Z-Order and sets keyboard
' focus to Excel.
'
' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
' NOTE: This will not work properly if a VBA Editor is open.
' If a VBA Editor window is open, the system will set focus
' to that window, rather than the XLMAIN window.
' !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
'
' This code should be able to activate the main window of any
' application whose main window class name is known. Just change
' the value of C_MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS to the window class of the
' main application window (e.g., "OpusApp" for Word).
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    Dim Res As Long     ' General purpose Result variable
    Dim XLHWnd As Long    ' Window handle of Excel
    Const C_MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS = "XLMAIN"
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' Get the window handle of the main
    ' Excel application window ("XLMAIN"). If
    ' more than one instance of Excel is running,
    ' you have no control over which
    ' instance's HWnd will be retrieved.
    ' Related Note: You MUST use vbNullString
    ' not an empty string "" in the call to
    ' FindWindow. When calling API functions
    ' there is a difference between vbNullString
    ' and an empty string "".
    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    XLHWnd = FindWindow(lpClassName:=C_MAIN_WINDOW_CLASS, _
                    lpWindowName:=vbNullString)
    If XLHWnd > 0 Then
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' If HWnd is > 0, FindWindow successfully
        ' found the Excel main application window.
        ' Move XLMAIN to the top of the
        ' Z-Order.
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Res = BringWindowToTop(HWnd:=XLHWnd)
        If Res = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "Error With BringWindowToTop:  " & _
                CStr(Err.LastDllError)
        Else
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            ' No error.
            ' Set keyboard input focus XLMAIN
            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            SetFocus HWnd:=XLHWnd
        End If
    Else
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        ' HWnd was 0. FindWindow couldn't
        ' find Excel.
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
        Debug.Print "Can't find Excel"
    End If
End Sub
```

Additional references:

1) [Toggle between Excel and IE](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/242533-toggle-between-excel-ie.html)

2) [VBA API declarations. Bring window to front , regardless of application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481674/vba-api-declarations-bring-window-to-front-regardless-of-application) ; link also in main body

3) [Return focus to excel after finishing downloading file with Internet explorer](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/other-software-applications/excel-and-web-browsers-help/131699-return-focus-to-excel-after-finishing-downloading-file-with-internet-explorer)

4) [Set focus back to the application window after showing userform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28042521/set-focus-back-to-the-application-window-after-showing-userform)

5) [Close the application with sendkeys like ALt F4](http://www.sqaforums.com/forums/hp-unified-functional-testing-uft-mercury-quicktest-pro-qtp/148780-close-application-sendkeys-like-alt-f4.html)

Comment: Generally you don't need `HTMLDocument` here, so Excel will not lost the focus. Try to extract the file downloading URL from the response parsing it by simple splitting (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35782811/2165759) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538937/2165759)), after that make another one XHR to download target file content, and save it with `ADODB.Stream` (check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41729562/2165759)).

Comment: @omegastripes Thanks for this. Too a bit of reading to get where you were coming from but got there. Much obliged.

Comment: So, have you came up with the code? It would be nice to answer with working solution.

Comment: @omegastripes I did, though actually for a different scenario. Used your process so I could, maybe later today, adapt to use as answer for this.

Comment: Have posted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @OmegaStripes and [@FlorentB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48747859/xhr-request-response-text-has-unexpected-character-set/48762654#48762654) for their input.

Using @OmegaStripes suggested method I:

1. Use XMLHTTP to get binary response content
2. Convert to UTF-8
3. Parse to extract the required URL
4. Use a new XMLHTTP to download binary
5. Use ADODB.Stream to write out file

Works a treat and no problems with shift in focus.

Notes: For step 3, I used the approach by [@KarstenW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524703/save-text-file-utf-8-encoded-with-vba) to write the string , the converted responseText string, out to a txt file for examination to determine how to access the URL of interest.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const adSaveCreateOverWrite As Byte = 2
Public Const url As String = "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/ambulance-quality-indicators/ambulance-quality-indicators-data-2017-18/"
Public Const adTypeBinary As Byte = 1
Public Const adTypeText As Byte = 2
Public Const adModeReadWrite As Byte = 3

Public Sub DownLoadFiles()

    Dim downLoadURL As String
    Dim aBody As String

    ' Download via XHR
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        ' Get binary response content
        aBody = BytesToString(.responseBody, "UTF-8")

    End With

    Dim respTextArr() As String
    respTextArr = Split(Split(aBody, "New AmbSYS Indicators")(0))
    downLoadURL = Split(respTextArr(UBound(respTextArr)), Chr$(34))(1)

    Dim urlArr() As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim bBody As Variant
    Dim sPath As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        .Open "GET", downLoadURL, False
        .send
        urlArr = Split(downLoadURL, "/")
        fileName = urlArr(UBound(urlArr))
        bBody = .responseBody
        sPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & fileName

    End With

    ' Save binary content to the xls file
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1
        .Open
        .Write bBody
        .SaveToFile sPath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        .Close
    End With
    ' Open saved workbook
    With Workbooks.Open(sPath, , False)

    End With

End Sub

Public Function BytesToString(ByVal bytes As Variant, ByVal charset As String) As String

    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Mode = adModeReadWrite
        .Type = adTypeBinary
        .Open
        .Write bytes
        .Position = 0
        .Type = adTypeText
        .charset = charset
        BytesToString = .ReadText
    End With
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

[For Excel 2013 please see here a solution that worked for me](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/4213b04f-870c-4118-8472-d79992aa1993/ms-project-2013-vba-macro-appactivate-microsoft-excel-runtime-error-5-invalid-procedural-call?)

In summary, change this:

```
AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
```

to

```
AppActivate "Excel
```

Note: a pause before the command can help (at least in my case):

```
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:1"))
```

Comment: I think this yielded the same problem for me I'm afraid though this has been useful in the past. +1 AppActivate is supposed to use what is in the window title but it is buggy.